# bs4 python module issue

Tags: windows, python, xml, python3

When I run the command:

```
python checker.py capture.xml indication NULL
```

I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "checker.py", line 1, in
>    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

so I decided install bs4 in Python 24 but when I do:

```
pip install bs4
```

I get this message:

> Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\program
>   files\python36\lib\site-packages Requirement already satisfied:
>   beautifulsoup4 in c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages (from
>   bs4) You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is
>   available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip
>   install --upgrade pip' command.

so indeed, the module is in that folder so I added c:\program files\python36\lib\ to the path environment variable just in case, but I'm getting the same thing.

Any idea on how to solve this, please?

Comment: So which version of python are you running? Python 2.4 or python 3.6? You have to add the executable to the path, then ensure the pip bootstrap is on. Then you should call the apropiate pip for the apropiate version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that your `python` command is referencing Python 2.4 (or some other installation of Python), while `pip` is referencing the version of `pip` installed with Python 3.6 in e.g. *C:\Program Files\Python36*. You can double-check the location of the `python.exe` called from the command line with `where python`.

Assuming the location returned by `where python` isn't e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe`, I would suggest checking both your User PATH and System Path environment variables. Make sure that e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python36` is present and remove any similar references to alternate Python installations.

The other (non-destructive) option is to simply specify the full path to the `python.exe` you wish to use e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" checker.py capture.xml indication NULL
```

**Notes**

- Since you have Python 3.6 installed, you may have the [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) installed as well. If this is the case, you can try replacing `python`  with e.g. `py -3.6` like so:

  ```
  py -3.6 checker.py capture.xml indication NULL
  ```
- I have made some assumptions about capitalization in the paths above. Obviously, you should use whatever capitalization suits your installation.
- While I don't believe this is relevant to answering your particular question, as a tip I would suggest installing Python into a directory without spaces (i.e. not *C:\Program Files*). This can help eliminate potential problems with file or folder paths in the future.